# Why does my jquery only kick-in after page refresh?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im having trouble with my jquery. Im using ajax to log me in to my account which inturn runs some php to change a few menus based on a set session. However because the page never redirects but the content changes it seems to be breaking all the jquery on the page until I click "refresh" and all the jquery works fine again.

How can I fix this issue?

I've added the parts of code with the breaking issues into this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UEn5G/)

Comment: use the new `$('.selector').on('click', function(){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this ended up being because I hadn't included the accordian jquery script into the external included php file that was being pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) feature:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Do your AJAX here
    $.ajax({ 
        // blah blah 
    });

    // Do the rest of your functionality here:
    $('a.class_name').on('click',function() { 
        // Change stuff when you click this link
    });

});
```

Comment: .live() is deprecated, you want .delegate() or .on() depending on your jQuery version.

Comment: @jamie, mate im not too litterate with jquery is there any chance of a js fiddle?

Comment: I've made my answer a bit easier. What bits are you struggling to understand?

Comment: @jamie what do I replace the a.class_name with? is this right? http://jsfiddle.net/UEn5G/1/

Comment: You basically select _whatever_ element you to add the click functionality to. So if you want to change something on the page when you click a particular link, give the link a unique class name and call it with `$('.unique_class_name').on('click',function() { });`

Comment: Also, don't define functions inside jQuery's `$(document).load(function() { });`

Answer (score 0):

As per Jamie's answer above. When using the event handlers such as click, you are only registering the event handler on the initial page load. Any subsequent load of **page elements** will not be registered.

What you need is to use delegate or live to register your event handlers. This way you are not registering the event with the element directly, but instead registering it with an element higher up, and the event will be delegated to your specific element. In your case, it will be delegated to your element.

Take a look at [this](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html).